# Why the end time is same as the start time in this shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

My shell script:

```
$ cat sh1.sh
#!/bin/bash
STAT=$(adb get-state)
DATE=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d_%H.%M.%S")
LOG_FILE_PREFIX="log"

LOGFILE="${LOG_FILE_PREFIX}_${DATE}.log"

run ()
{
    #echo Start at $(date)>$LOGFILE
    echo Start at $(date)

    adb logcat -v time -b main -b system >>$LOGFILE

#   echo End at $(date)>>$LOGFILE
}

#trap "echo End at $(date)>>$LOGFILE" INT TERM EXIT
#trap "echo End at $(date)>>$LOGFILE" INT
trap "echo End at $(date)" INT QUIT EXIT TERM

if [ $STAT != "device" ]; then
    echo "please connect to your phone using usb wire and re-run this script file!"
    exit
else
    run
fi
```

the result:

```
$ ./sh1.sh
Start at 2016年 1月29日 星期五 18时21分22秒 CST
^CEnd at 2016年 1月29日 星期五 18时21分22秒 CST
End at 2016年 1月29日 星期五 18时21分22秒 CST
```

I want to get the end time through trap INT, but wrong, why?

Comment: @anubhava Thats only used to name the log file though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should single-quote the `trap` commands in order to expand subshells and variables only when it is going to be executed.

```
trap 'echo End at $(date)' INT QUIT EXIT TERM
```

With double quotes, the date will be interpolated when you set up the trap, not when the code within it executes.